# Существует ли аппаратная поддержка аудиокодеков?

Tags: c++, windows, аудио, железо, кодек

Существует ли аппаратная поддержка аудиокодеков. Если да, то каких? Посредством каких библиотек можно получить аппаратное ускорение?

Читал стандарт USB, в стандарте USB-audio заложена поддержка кодеков, в том числе mp3, но USB-звуковые карты ещё не так распространены.

- Поддерживают ли mp3 и ААС современные карты или используется програмный кодек (например Realtek HD Audio)?
- Какие именно кодеки поддерживаются аудиокартами?
- Какие с++ библиотеки поддерживаю воспроизведение через аппаратное сжатие?
- Сколько аудиопотоков одновременно может кодировать аудиокарта?

Или производители звуковых карт не стали заморачиваться с кодеками, и mp3 поддерживают только некоторые USB-звуковые карты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Звуковые адаптеры с поддержкой аппаратного кодирования/декодирования сжатого звука существуют, но, в основном, это очень старые модели. В качестве примера можно привести [Turtle Beach Santa Cruz](http://www.neoseeker.com/Articles/Hardware/Reviews/santacruz/), относящуюся к началу 2000-х годов. Это реализовывалось с помощью разработки нестандартного DirectShow-фильтра, который принимал на вход поток типа MP3 и передавал его напрямую в видеокарту, минуя обычную цепочку MP3 Decoder - WaveOut renderer. Таким образом, любое DirectShow-приложение могло воспроизводить звук с использованием аппаратного декодирования. В те времена это было существенно, так как процессоры были маломощны, а применявшиеся ОС Windows 9x не очень хорошо умели управлять их загрузкой, так что воспроизведение звука исключительно программными средствами приводило к прерывистому звучанию при высокой загрузке процессора.

Но сейчас большинство распространенных звуковых адаптеров его не поддерживает. Более того, начиная с Windows Vista звуковая модель вообще не содержит никакой поддержки аппаратного ускорения для работы со звуком - даже смешивание звуковых потоков от разных приложений выполняется программно. Так было сделано главным образом потому, что производительность процессоров сильно возросла, а затраты времени на обработку аудио остались теми же - т.е. обработка аудио стала занимать исчезающе малый процент мощности процессора. Если открыть воспроизведение mp3 на современном компьютере и посмотреть использование ЦП проигрывателем в диспетчере задач, оно будет почти всегда 0%, достигая 1% только в редкие моменты.

От аппаратного декодирования отказались, так как оно приводило бы к ненужному удорожанию устройств, не давая при этом почти никакой выгоды. Конечно, если кто-то разрабатывает профессиональные звуковые карты, для которых это имеет значение, они могут также предоставлять нестандартные драйвера и DirectShow-фильтры для этих целей. Только для того, чтобы извлечь из них пользу, понадобится специальный софт - современные версии Windows Media Player и приложения, использующие его движок, скорее всего их "не подхватят".

Comment: В каком-то из датащитов серии AC97 видел аппаратную поддержку mp3, не получается сейчас снова найти. У последних карточек маскимум что есть это multistreaming (аппаратное смешивание).

Comment: Раздел "Outbound Frame – Multiple SDOs"  я трактовал как возможноть апаратно смешивать аудиопотоки, но возможно я не так понял датащит. ссылка на realtek http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/datasheets/ALC888_1-0.pdf

Comment: @nick_n_a Скорее всего да, но документ от 2006 года, когда Vista еще была в бете. У более новых наверное еще меньше аппаратных возможностей.